# Where should dbus session-local.conf be created?

Tags: session, dbus

I need to allow root user to connect to session busses of other users. What I did was add
`<allow user="root"/>` under `<policy context="default">` and it worked like a charm.

However, it is recommended not to edit `/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf` file but to create `session-local.conf` and make changes there. (This is the first paragraph of `session.conf`:

> This configuration file controls the per-user-login-session message
> bus.
> Add a session-local.conf and edit that rather than changing this
> file directly.)

My problem is that I don't know where to create it. Tried with `/usr/share/dbus-1/session-local.conf`does not seem to work.

Comment: Must be `/usr/share/dbus-1/session-local.conf` though. The `session.conf` file should `include` the `session-local.conf` file, or otherwise you should start the `dbus-daemon` with the other config file.

Comment: To be clear: `man dbus-daemon` says this: "The standard systemwide and per-session message bus setups are configured in the files "/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf" and "/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf". These files normally
       <include> a system-local.conf or session-local.conf in /etc/dbus-1; you can put local overrides in those files to avoid modifying the primary configuration files." So if there is no `<include>`, put it in yourself.

Comment: Ah, there is ```<include ignore_missing="yes">/etc/dbus-1/session-local.conf</include>``` so I guess ```/etc/dbus-1/session-local.conf``` it is. Thanks